# What's the best new development tool of 2009?

Tags: java, sql-server, vb.net, developer-tools

I am looking to do a presentation at work to our development team. I was wondering if their is any new tool which would be easy to demonstrate. It is just an after work thing for talking about new technologies. Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you chose those particular tags?  Are you limiting question to those 3 technologies?

Comment: Maybe you should lurk around here a little longer.

Comment: Hasn't it only been two months?

Comment: @Outlaw Programmer

Those are the tags as they are most relevant to my background. However I would be interested in hearing about anything outstanding. Its a very open topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[historical debugging](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VisualStudio/Historical-Debugger-and-Test-Impact-Analysis-in-Visual-Studio-Team-System-2010/). is implemented in VS.net version 10. can't wait until this makes it to the java platform. introduces by the end of 2008, but this is recent enough, methinks.

Comment: How is this different from the Omniscient Debugger (ODB)? From reading the description it sounds exactly the same.

Comment: This is actually very interesting. I'm looking at both at the moment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

I would say, the biggest thing in 2009 so far, and probably for the whole year, has been the [release](http://GBracha.BlogSpot.Com/2009/02/newspeak-prototype-escapes-into-wild.html) of the [prototype](http://NewspeakLanguage.Org/downloads/) of [Gilad Bracha](http://GBracha.BlogSpot.Com/)'s [Newspeak Programming Language](http://NewspeakLanguage.Org/), and its accompanying [GUI Framework Brazil](http://Blog.3plus4.Org/2008/05/08/which-is-which-in-newspeak-ui-brazil/), the [Application Development Framework Hopscotch](http://Blog.3plus4.Org/2008/06/20/which-is-which-in-newspeak-ui-hopscotch/) and the [Hopscotch IDE and debugger](http://GBracha.BlogSpot.Com/2008/11/dynamic-ides-for-dynamic-languages.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can't imagine any new development tool released in 2009 which is worth to demonstrate.

But maybe you can take a look into the future and tell them whats coming in a few months. For example for all the .NET guys out there you can tell something about the new languages like F# and IronPython coming in Visual Studio 2010. Whats the difference between them compared to C# or VB.net .... stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell you what the best of 2009 is seeing as how we are only in March. It also might be best if you gave us some more information concerning what types of tools you are interested in, the systems you develop, etc. It may also be that some of our suggestions will end up being from 2008 and you just may not have heard of them or tried them before.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing that happened last year (as far as I'm concerned anyway) was the emergence and rise to prominence of several high quality, open source, distributed version control systems. Namely:

- [git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/)
- [bazaar](http://bazaar-vcs.org/)

... but you probably already knew that.